# Using nested foreach loops to unset objects in array not working as expected?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of objects which have `id` and `parentId` attributes. The `id` value is unique, but more than one object may have the same `parentId` value.

If more than one object has the same `parentId` value, I want to remove all but one (i.e. remove the "siblings").

I thought I could do this easily with nested `foreach` loops, but it's not working as I expected.

Here's an example:

```
$objArray = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = $i;
    $obj->parentId = 1;

    $objArray[] = $obj;
}

for($i = 2; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = $i;
    $obj->parentId = 2;

    $objArray[] = $obj;
}

echo 'Before unsetting siblings:<pre>';
print_r($objArray);
echo '</pre>';

// loop over $objArray and remove elements with the same ->parentId (leaving one)
foreach ($objArray as $keyOuter => $objOuter) {
    foreach ($objArray as $keyInner => $objInner) {
        if ($objInner->id != $objOuter->id             // if the inner object is NOT the same as the outer object (i.e. it's a different object)
         && $objInner->parentId == $objOuter->parentId // and if the parent IDs are the same
        ) {
            unset($objArray[$keyInner]); // unset the inner object
        }
    }
}

echo 'After unsetting siblings:<pre>';
print_r($objArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Before unsetting siblings:

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 0
            [parentId] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parentId] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parentId] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parentId] => 2
        )

)

After unsetting siblings:

Array
(
)
```

I expected the first and third objects in the array to remain after the `foreach` loops, but as you can see all of the objects in the array are deleted.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) states that modifying an array while being looped over with a foreach leads to undefined behaviour (the foreach loop uses a pointer internal to the array, the same the one used with function like `next`, `current`, etc.). I'm even wondering if 2 nested loops should actually work given the explanation.

Comment: @didierc I reread the documentation and do not see anything on what you said.

Comment: You are correct. The issue is that one should not modify the internal pointer, I wrongly extrapolated to any modification to the array. Here's the quote: *As foreach relies on the internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected Behavior*.

Comment: Note that still, using a foreach within a foreach should have the outer loop be disturbed by the inner loop resetting the internal pointer.

Comment: @didierc I see nested foreach loops in PHP code *all the time*, though?

Comment: On the **same** array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this line in your inner loop:

```
echo 'Matched id #'.$objOuter->id.' parent #'.$objOuter->parentId.' with id #'.$objInner->id.' parent #'.$objInner->parentId."\r\n";
```

Which yielded:

> Matched id #0 parent #1 with id #1 parent #1
>
> Matched id #1 parent #1 with id #0 parent #1
>
> Matched id #2 parent #2 with id #3 parent #2
>
> Matched id #3 parent #2 with id #2 parent #2

Another demonstration (`!!` indicates no match/deletion, `==` indicates a parent match with deletion):

```
0/1!!0/1 0/1==1/1 0/1!!2/2 0/1!!3/2 
1/1==0/1 1/1!!2/2 1/1!!3/2 
2/2!!2/2 2/2==3/2 
3/2==2/2
```

See the pattern? While your inner loop is getting the latest version of `$objArray` after you have `unset` the element that has been matched, your outer loop doesn't have the new version because `foreach` actually keeps a temporary cloned array for the `$objOuter` and `$keyOuter` values.

Here's a proof of concept:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);

foreach ($array as $a) {
    if (isset($array)) unset($array);
    echo $a;
}
```

Output:

```
1234
```

Or this:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);

foreach ($array as $a) {
    $array[3] = 100;
    echo $a; // Output is still 1234
}
```

Or this:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);

foreach ($array as $a) {
    if (isset($array[3])) unset($array[3]);
    echo $a; // Yet again 1234
}
```

If `$array` doesn't exist anymore, why does the loop still keep going? By the same logic, why isn't the output of my second example `123100`? The same flaw/bug exists with your outer loop.

I'd rather create a new filtered array instead of trying to delete from the original with nested loops:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($objArray as $obj) {
    if (!isset($newArray[$obj->parentId])) { // Use the index to test for existing parent IDs
        $newArray[$obj->parentId] = $obj;
    }
}
// Optional - use array_values to get rid of parentId in the indices
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
// or you can just do this if you want to replace $objArray
$objArray = array_values($newArray);
unset($newArray);
```

You can also keep another array of existing parent keys and then delete from the existing array if the key already exists:

```
$existingParents = array();
foreach ($objArray as $key => $obj) {
    if (isset($existingParents[$obj->parentId])) {
        unset($objArray[$key]);
    } else {
        $existingParents[$obj->parentId] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "your loop is too liberal"?

Comment: @Nate Gave some clarification. Try my proof of concept code for yourself to see what I mean.

Comment: I really like your updated solution. That's probably much more efficient than nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines of your for loops are the same, use var_dump to make sure for yourself:

```
foreach ($objArray as $keyOuter => $objOuter) {
    foreach ($objArray as $keyInner => $objInner) { 
        var_dump($objArray, $objInner); //the same object is returned
        ...
```

so technically the objOuter will always equal objInner in the first run of the second foreach, hence deleting the object, at the end you will have deleted all objects.

for this piece of code give your variable a different name:

```
for($i = 2; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = $i;
    $obj->parentId = 2;

    $objArray2[] = $obj; //instead of $objArray
}
```

This is the final code and it works the way you wanted it to:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = $i;
    $obj->parentId = 1;

    $objArray[] = $obj;
}

for($i = 2; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = $i;
    $obj->parentId = 2;

    $objArray2[] = $obj;
}

echo 'Before unsetting siblings:<pre>';
print_r($objArray);
echo '</pre>';

foreach ($objArray as $keyOuter => $objOuter) {
    foreach ($objArray2 as $keyInner => $objInner) {
        if ($objInner->id != $objOuter->id 
            && $objInner->parentId == $objOuter->parentId) {
        unset($objArray[$keyInner]); // unset the inner object
        }
    }
}

echo 'After unsetting siblings:<pre>';
print_r($objArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
$objArray = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = $i;
    $obj->parentId = 1;

    $objArray[] = $obj;
}

for($i = 2; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = $i;
    $obj->parentId = 2;

    $objArray[] = $obj;
}

echo 'Before unsetting siblings:<pre>';
print_r($objArray);
echo '</pre>';

// loop over $objArray and remove elements with the same ->parentId (leaving one)
$max = count($objArray);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $objOuter = $objArray[$i];
    foreach ($objArray as $i2=>$objInner) {
        if ($objInner->id != $objOuter->id             // if the inner object is NOT the same as the outer object (i.e. it's a different object)
         && $objInner->parentId == $objOuter->parentId // and if the parent IDs are the same
        ) {
            unset($objArray[$i2]);
            $max=$max-1;// unset the inner object
        }
    }
}

echo 'After unsetting siblings:<pre>';
print_r($objArray);
echo '</pre>';
```